# Difference between CIAttributeMax and CIAttributeSliderMax

Tags: core-image, cifilter

What is the difference between `CIAttributeMax` and `CIAttributeSliderMax` (or `CIAttributeMin` and `CIAttributeSliderMin`)?

I found values related to `CIAttributeMax` and `CIAttributeSliderMax` differs by some filters, e. g. `CIHistogramDisplayFilter`'s `inputHeight` defines `CIAttributeMax` as 200 and `CIAttributeSliderMax` as 100.

Does this mean that I am able to set values right above 100?

Comment: I have the same question. Any update so far?

Answer (score 0):

I've never found any *official* reason for having two sets of max/min. The most logical reason (to me) appears to be how (an old Objective-C OS X v10.5 filter browser called) [ImageKit](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Conceptual/ImageKitProgrammingGuide/IKFilterBrowser/IKFilterBrowser.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004907-CH8-SW3) is wired up.

If you want, you can also use the canned filters or a subset in your app, and the bottom line is **both** sets of max/min are "guidelines". For instance, try `CIEdges`, putting in a a value above max. (I call the effect "edges with steroids".)

Some filters the values outside the range make no difference, some do. You need to experiment the specific filter to know.